# Grouping values by a column and getting min value of another with another column

Tags: sql

My table structure is as follows

```
userId    period    pcount
a         01/03      100
a         02/03      150
a         03/03      200
b         02/03      250
...and so on..
```

I wish to get the row which has the minimum pcount for each userid, so the result for userid a ought to be as below..

```
a     01/03   100
```

If I did not want the period value, I could have grouped the table by userId and selected userId and MIN of pcount.

But, since I need the period as well, what should I do..

Though I'm using SQL Server on azure,it might change and so would appreciate standard ansi sql query.

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general these kind of requests are handled through `ROW_NUMBER`

```
Select * From 
(
select row_number() Over(Partition by userId Order by pcount asc) as rn,*
From yourtable
) A
Where Rn = 1
```

Another approach using `INNER JOIN` works with most of the DBMS

```
SELECT A.*
FROM   yourtable A
       INNER JOIN (SELECT userId,
                          Min(pcount) AS M_pcount
                   FROM   yourtable
                   GROUP  BY userId) B
               ON A.userId = B.userId
                  AND A.pcount = B.M_pcount
```